# Cannot open a .air file even with Adobe AIR installed

Tags: windows-7, windows, adobe-air

I douwnloaded a .air file (designview.air, to have a design viewer for flashdevelop). Also I have installed Adobe AIR, but still i cannot open this file. After the installation setup is finished i don't have any interface with the adobe AIR nor put it as the predefined program to open a .air file. Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way of installing .air files. As generally done in windows i expected that Adobe AIR would have a GUI interface, which don't. The way to install a .air file is to look the folder where Adobe AIR is intalled and run an exe that is called Adobe AIR Application Installer.exe. This will launch the GUI to intall a .air file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to right click on the air file, and select open file with. In the window, click on browse, and navigate to the installation of adobe air. Make sure the box is checked for always use this program and then hit ok.

This site may help with the installation location. [LINK](https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/determine-version-air-runtime.html)

Answer (score 0):

I looked all over for a solution for not being able to open a .air file on a Mac Pro. I kept getting a message saying it was an incorrect file type. I reloaded Adobe Air, I re-downloaded the .air file. Nothing helped. The simple answer was to go to the .air file - it happened to BE in my Download folder - and, instead of double clicking on it as I had been doing, Right Click, then use the Open With, Other, and locate the executable file called Adobe AIR Application Installer. The .air file ran beautifully. Thanks to Restro Fad for getting me most of the way there.